Azure API Management Credentials Manager missing "scope" field for generic OAuth 2.0 CCF and Entra External ID
I have issues getting an access token using client credentials in API Management Credentials Manager.
I am using Entra External ID for external tenants as IdP.
Credentials Provider details:

Identity provider: OAuth 2.0

Grant type: client credentials

Authorization URL: empty

Refresh URL: empty

Token URL: https://<tenant id>.ciamlogin.com/<tenant id>/oauth2/v2.0/token


The error:

Failed to acquire access token for service using client credentials flow: IdentityProvider=oauth2. Correlation Id=c9b9d0e2-cf03-42a5-8e3e-0327a8841f3a, UTC TimeStamp=6/5/2024 1:24:23 PM, Error: Failed to exchange client credentials for token. Response code=BadRequest, Details:
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADSTS90014: The required field 'scope' is missing from the credential. Ensure that you have all the necessary parameters for the login request. Trace ID: 14689e05-8545-45af-a0d1-3cb70a090000 Correlation ID: e04d620f-5340-42db-82fd-6e9b6a5a1553 Timestamp: 2024-06-05 13:24:23Z","error_codes":[90014],"timestamp":"2024-06-05 13:24:23Z","trace_id":"14689e05-8545-45af-a0d1-3cb70a090000","correlation_id":"e04d620f-5340-42db-82fd-6e9b6a5a1553","error_uri":"https://<tenant id>.ciamlogin.com/error?code=90014"}

And that's expected cause there is no way to provide scope.
I managed to get the token using Azure Active Directory v1 as an Identity Provider.

Identity provider: Azure Active Directory v1

Grant type: client credentials

Authorization URL: https://<tenant id>.ciamlogin.com

Resource URL: <Application ID URI>

Tenant Id: <tenant id>


The questions are:

Can this workaround be used in production?
Is there a correct way to make it work?


As you are making use of v2.0 endpoint that is https://.ciamlogin.com//oauth2/v2.0/token, you need pass scope as parameter not resource parameter

client_id=ClientID &scope=<Application ID URI> &client_secret=Secret &grant_type=client_credentials this must be the request

Yes, you are right; I need to pass a scope parameter, but how do I do it? Scope and other parameters should be part of the body, not the URL.

Yes, scope must be the part of body. I guess currently you are passing resource in the body just change it as scope

I am using Credentials Manager from API Management, a UI tool. I need help with that tool, not with OAuth, in general

It is in the question, just as text, not a picture

Can you try passing token URL as https://.ciamlogin.com//oauth2/token

yes, I tried that before; I am getting: "AADSTS500207: The account type can't be used for the resource you're trying to access.

Is the problem only with external tenants?

Try passing authorization URL as  https://.ciamlogin.com/

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

What are you passing for Resource URL: ?
The resource URL shouldnt contain ./default

The thing with the Resource URL works. But that is a workaround as I see it, and I need to know if it is safe to go with it in production.

Thanks for trying to help, I also tried a bunch of things but it seems the trial-and-error method doesn't work here

Yes it is safe in production too, Can I post it as an answer? By default resource URL shouldnt contain /.default as it is using v1 endpoint

What makes you say it is safe to go with it into production?

The error "AADSTS90014: The required field 'scope' is missing from the credential. Ensure that you have all the necessary parameters for the login request" usually occurs if you are making use of Credential manager and configuring Client credential flow for OAuth 2.0.
Configured Client credential flow for OAuth 2.0 under Credential manager
-   Identity provider: OAuth 2.0  
-   Grant type: client credentials   
-   Authorization URL: empty  
-   Refresh URL: empty 
-   Token URL: https://<tenant id>.XXX.com/<tenant id>/oauth2/v2.0/token


Initially, I got the same error :

Hence to resolve the error, you can make use of OAuth 2.0 and pass scope like below:
Go to your APIM instance -> Select OAuth 2.0 + OpenID Connect -> Select OAuth 2.0 -> Add -> Select Client credential flow and paste the values

Now while calling the APIs select OAuth 2.0 and add OAuth2 service that you created:


OAUTH 2.0 is added as a separate feature itself in APIM.
Scope field is not present in credential manager for OAUTh 2 for now. You can raise a feature request for this with the product team.

Reference:
Protect API's using OAuth 2.0 in APIM - Microsoft Community Hub by Sherry Sahni

There are no errors when I use Azure Active Directory v1 as an Identity Provider.
The error you mentioned in your post happens when OAuth 2 is used as an Identity Provider. And when I use OAuth 2, there is no way to specify the scope, as I wrote in the question.

@TarasBilynskyi As I mentioned in the answer select Oauth 2.0 + OpenID blade to connect to OAuth 2 is used as an Identity Provider. Please check the last screenshot

You can pass the scope in Default scope tab

OAUTH 2.0 is added as a separate feature itself in APIM

@TarasBilynskyi  Scope field is not present in credential manager for OAUTh 2 for now. You can raise a feature request for this with the product team. Hence make use of   Oauth 2.0 + OpenID blade to connect to OAuth 2

Check this for Oauth 2.0 https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/protect-api-s-using-oauth-2-0-in-apim/ba-p/2309538

@TarasBilynskyi Please check the above and the last screenshot mentioned in the answer and let me know if it works

@TarasBilynskyi any update on this issue? Did the issue resolve?
